# Primefaces Datatable global filtering not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable, filtering

I've been trying for hours to get the filter to work on a datatable, I've followed the tutorial and I've also read a lot of questions on stackoverflow, but it still doesn't work...Any help would be appreciated!

```
<p:dataTable value="#{filterThreads.threads}" var="t" 
                emptyMessage="No threads found with given criteria"
                lazy="false"
                paginator="true"
                rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100"
                 widgetVar="threadsTable" tableStyleClass="table table-striped" style="border:none"

                 filteredValue="#{filterThreads.filteredThreads}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('threadsTable').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>
                    <p:column filterBy="#{t.uuid}" filterStyle="display:none">
                        <f:facet name="header">UUID</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{t.uuid}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column filterBy="#{t.initiator}" filterStyle="display:none">
                        <f:facet name="header">Initiator</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{t.initiator}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column filterBy="#{t.email}" filterStyle="display:none">
                        <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{t.email}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column filterBy="#{t.subject}" filterStyle="display:none">
                        <f:facet name="header">Subject</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{t.subject}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column filterBy="#{t.date}" filterStyle="display:none">
                        <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{t.date}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look into http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml.

Comment: What did you debug? Why did the other questions not work? Does the showcase example work? Lots of things you can and should do yourself. Including reading [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and providing version info

Comment: @Unknown I've already looked into it and followed it. I can't for the life of me see what's wrong.

Comment: Could you specify what is the value you have entered in the global filter and what do you want to filter?

Comment: @Unknown Not sure if I understood what you're asking, but I've entered a string to try and find 'Threads', which are composed by email,uuid,subject,initiator and date, all of them are strings as well.
I want to get back one or more Threads that contain a string that I pass in the search bar. It just returns all empty for some reason. When I don't search anything, the datatable shows up the data just fine, but if I type anything it'll lose all elements and they won't return until I refresh the page.

Comment: Default filterMatchMode is startsWith. You try entering the exact 'email' for example to check the filter.

Comment: Have you tried this `filterMatchMode="contains"` ?

Comment: @Unknown I've tried that, still blank :/

Comment: @techipank I've set it to that, still no results.

Comment: can you post your screenshot

Answer (score 3):

I finally found what was wrong and decided to post here. I forgot that I needed the 
    < h:form>< /h:form>
 tags enclosing the datatable. /facepalm

Comment: I fail to see how you solved it. _"I needed the tags inclosing the datatable"_ ???

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry, didn't notice that the tags were hidden in the comment! Edited